# iTerm text search is in reverse order

Tags: iterm

I'm running iTerm2. When do a text search <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>, pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> moves the highlighted occurrence back (the previous occurrence). Is there a way to make it move to the next (forward) occurrence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching in reverse is apparently how iTerm's search works by design (see https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/4491).

As a user, I also find this design decision confusing.

If you would like to make `Find Next` / `Find Previous` in iTerm behave consistently with other apps, here are the proper keybinding overrides to add in `System Preferences > Keyboard`.

*Note that I had to restart iTerm for the keybindings to fully take effect.*

[image: iterm find keybinding overrides]

Comment: Can I ask what is going on with the "Function Keys" entry in your settings here? I do not have that on Mac os mojave, I don't think I've ever seen it

Comment: @DevinGRhode It looks like `Function Keys` is related to the MacBook Pro touch bar.  Any chance you are working on a non-touch bar machine?

Comment: I was working on a non-touchbar machine, yes.

Comment: This is a stupid design decision but thanks for the workaround

Answer (score 2):

Like @Taylor D. Edmiston said, this is iTerm's default behavior. However, there's now an iTerm2 setting in `Preferences > Advanced > General` to revert that behavior to "normal" when set to "No" (next is down, previous is up):

https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/2049

> Commit a99ed9b1 adds an advanced preference named "Swap Find Next and Find Previous". It defaults to "Yes". When disabled, search acts like a standard application. The only thing the setting does not affect is key bindings, which presumably work the way you want, and are also labeled "find up" and "find down" which is unambiguous.

The numeration is still "backward" (e.g. 1/20 will be the lowest down text match) but otherwise works the same as you would expect of other applications.

[image: Swap Find Next and Find Previous Setting]

Answer (score -2):

Try using Shift+Enter to reach the next occurrence.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything may be deleted.

Comment: I apologize, I'm new here. I tried to find documentation on the internet to back up my personal experience, and I found this thread. In the future, should I find a source on the web with my answers? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/iterm2-discuss/find/iterm2-discuss/XL55TiIlPOw/-rNB1dp1VA0J

Comment: That's ok...it's how we learn.....but I don't belive shift-enter does anything in this context.  You might want to try Cmd-G or just Enter

Comment: Cmd-G also works in reverse